# Calculating the win/loss ratio per team

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

sport_a_statistics:

```
id      team_id     game_id     points
1       1           1           7   
2       2           1           8
3       3           2           6   
4       1           2           9
```

sport_b_statistics:

```
id      team_id     game_id     points
1       1           3           2   
2       2           3           1
3       3           4           3   
4       1           4           10
```

I want to calculate the win/loss ratio for each team. This includes making sure to capture the wins and losses from both sport tables since my tournament involves 2 sports. So the output I'm looking for is the following:

```
team_id    wins    loss    ratio
1          3       1       3.0
2          1       1       1.0
3          0       2       0.0
```

I can't wrap my head around how I would do this in one query.

Comment: "I have the following table".  Then you show two tables.

Comment: Check the post again.

Comment: That two tables should really be one with an extra column denoting the sport.

Comment: No because I'm measuring different statistics for each sport. Just didn't show it here.

Comment: Are ties wins or losses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no ties, you can use window functions and `union all`:

```
select team_id,
       sum(points = max_points) as num_wins,
       sum(points < max_points) as num_losses,
       sum(points = max_points) / nullif(sum(points < max_points), 0) as ratio
from ((select a.*, max(points) over (partition by game_id) as max_points
       from sport_a a
      ) union all
      (select b.*, max(points) over (partition by game_id) as max_points
       from sport_b b
      ) 
     ) ab
group by team_id
```

---

Made a small edit ^